# Search the position of a column in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, search, app-inventor

I am searching... and I don't find how can I  find in SQlite what is the position of an item in the column.

When i use `ROW_NUMBER()` i get:

> ERROR: near "(": syntax error (code 1)

```
SELECT Nom ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY Score) AS Rownumber 
FROM tableau
```

I'm using MIT App Inventor with [Taifun extension sqlite](https://puravidaapps.com/sqlite.php)

Other question how to know which item is in position 2 (or another number) in the column?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: At least, you should post your query here.Anw, Are u sure that  the version of sql server which u are using  , does  it support ROW_NUMBER

Comment: Please provide the SQL you have attempted and some sample data

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: How to post my database? It's included in my app, the database is empty at the beginning and the app add column and index...

Comment: SQLite does not support `row_number()`.  Do some investigation. If that doesn't answer your question, then ask another question.

Comment: What about using `ROWID`? see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235189/1545993 ... you might want to do some SQLite tutorials...

Comment: Can anybody confirm the `over` is sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

`ROW_NUMBER()` is an ANSI-standard function.  However, not all databases use it.  For instance, SQLite, MySQL, and MS Access (among others) do not support this functionality.

Presumably, you are using one of these database that does not support this function.

I would suggest that you research what database you are using.  Then, try investigating how to implement the functionality you want using that database.  If you can't figure out how, ask *another* question, providing sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: I know now I use sqlite !

Answer (score 0):

If this is indeed the code you are running:

```
SELECT Nom ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY Score) AS Rownumber FROM tableau
```

Then what is `Nom`? This is a syntax error in practically every implementation. What you are probably looking to do is:

```
SELECT Nom, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY Score) AS Rownumber FROM tableau
```

Notice the comma after `Nom`.